# \t works on irb but not in my ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 path variables as per below:

```
path1 = "../home/result_file.erb"
path2 = "../my_folder/Data_file.erb"
```

I create an anchor tag links sting to pass it to my erb file. The string code is:

```
file_links_string = "<a href='#{path1}'>Result Report</a>\t\t\t<a href='#{path2}'>Data Report</a>"
p file_links_string
```

When I do `puts "<a href='../home/result_file.erb'>Result Report</a>\t\t\t<a href='../my_folder/Data_file.erb'>Data Report</a>"` on irb, it prints the two href tags with tab spaces in between.

But my `p file_links_string` prints `"<a href='../home/result_file.erb'>Result Report</a>\t\t\t<a href='../my_folder/Data_file.erb'>Data Report</a>"` on console. Looks like it considers '\t' as a string.

On my webpage I am getting `Result Report` and `Data Report` next to each other without tab spaces in between.

Am I creating the string incorrectly? Or do I need to add anything? I am using 2.1.1 ruby.

Comment: HTML parsers consider any amount of spaces as single space. That’s why you’ll never get a margin by using `\t` or any other kind of space in HTML output. Change `\t\t\t` to `#{'&nbsp;'*10}` to get the desired result in HTML. Don’t take `p` output into account, it makes assumptions on what you want to see :)

Comment: Oh ok. Let me try #{'&nbsp;'*10}. But I curious why printing the string from ruby after creating it has \t\t\t. I understand html parsing spaces.

Comment: Use `puts` instead of `p` to see the string content as is in the console.

Comment: It's considered poor HTML programming to try to force spacing using whitespace. Instead, you should use CSS to set the location or word spacing.

Comment: @tech_human What you need is a CSS rule to add some margin or padding. Whitespace is not a formatting tool in HTML. Try: `<a href='...' style='padding-left:20px'>` and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Printing the string using puts gives the expected output. @mudasobwa - nbsp worked too. But since CSS is the best choice here, I am going with adding css to anchor tag.